# Use pivotal cloud foundry rabbitmq and mysql service using vcap service for spring data jpa application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I am able to use RABBITMQ and MYSQLSERVICES which is on pivotal.While binding services I am able to get the Credentials and using that credentials in my application.properties for spring data jpa project.

But this configuration that I am using is hard-coded in application.Properties To Make this configuration dynamically I came to know that we can use vcap services provided by pivotal.

So want to use run-time credentials for rabbimq and mysql.

My Code is below for reference.

File: application.propeties

```
rabbitmq.host=hostname
rabbitmq.virtual-host=vhost
rabbitmq.username=username
rabbitmq.password=password
rabbit.mainqueue=queue name
rabbit.errorqueue=erro queue name
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://hostname:postno
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
server.port=8000
```

The below is the repository file

```
package com.redistomysql.consumer.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface tblemployee_personal_infoRepository extends JpaRepository<tblemployee_personal_info, Long> {

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The link for reference **http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2016/05/approaches-to-binding-spring-boot.html** 
Set this configuration in application-cloud.yml for Mysql
---

spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${vcap.services.mydb.credentials.jdbcUrl}
    username: ${vcap.services.mydb.credentials.username}
    password: ${vcap.services.mydb.credentials.password}

    The config for rabbitMq:
System.getEnv("VCAP_SERVICES")
```

The dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- If you intend to deploy the app on Cloud Foundry, add the following -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-heroku-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

**The manifest.yml**

---
applications:
  - name: redistomysql-consumer
    path: target/redistomysql-consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    memory: 1024M
    env:
      JAVA_OPTS: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
    services:
      - es-mysql-db
      - es-consumer-rabbitmq-service

buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git

env:
    JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'
```